# Infinite integral domain with finite characteristic.

Tags: abstract-algebra

$\mathbb{F}_p(X)=\Big \{\frac {f}{g} \:\Big|\: f,g \in \mathbb{F}_p[X], g\neq 0 \Big \}$

Where $p$ is prime, it is an infinite field with finite characteristic.

I need an example of an infinite integral domain which is not a field with finite characteristic.

Comment: $\mathbb{F}_p[X]$?

Comment: Rational functions coefficients in $\mathbb{F}_p$

Comment: @ThirumalPachaiyappan I think that Mindlack provided the example you're looking for... namely $\mathbb{F}_p[X]$.

Comment: No, I mean that $\mathbb{F}_p[X]$ is an infinite integral domain with finite characteristic but is not a field.

Comment: As said, just the polynomial ring over a finite field.

Comment: Given the possibility of coefficients cancelling, it perhaps takes a smidgen of work to confirm that $\Bbb F_p[X]$ is in fact an integral domain (consider the lowest coefficients of any product) and is not a field (consider the highest coefficients of any product).

Comment: Next time please search for similar questions before posting.